# How can i upload Android .apk File On BlackBerry World

Tags: android, deployment, blackberry

I want to know how can i deploy android .apk file  On BlackBerry World.

I have already Created BlackBerry Vendor Account.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For upload your Android to Blackberry App world, you need:

1) Verify, that your app meet requirements for Blackberry app world.

"Because some of the Android SDK APIs are not supported, or are only partially supported, by the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps, not all APK files will be readily compatible with the BlackBerry PlayBook tablet."

You should use for that " apk2barVerifier"

Here is documentation:

http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/android/documentation/preverify_apk_files_using_apk2barverify_playbook.html

2) If your app meets the Blackberry App World requirements - next step is to repack your app to bar.

Here is step by step guide:

Gui repackager:

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/rpkg_with_apk_pkgr_tool.html

Command-line app repackager( gives you more options ):

http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/android/documentation/converting_apk_to_bar_files_playbook.html

3) After repackaging, you can finally upload your app to Blackberry.

That's how you should do that:

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/publsh_your_app_to_appworld.html